# Place node a fixed length along a transparent bisector?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

Doing some hocus-pocus to mark the angle of a triangle a fixed length away from the point and I want to now place a node midway between the point and the arc so I can label the value of the angle.

I'm aware that the way I've constructed the arc means that there isn't a defined midpoint for that particular section that's showing (for reasons beyond the scope of the question `\tkzMarkAngle` and `\tkzLabelAngle` are not options), which is why I'm thinking the way to do this would be with a bisector, but I can't figure out how to place the node.

Open to any other suggestions also.

```
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
  \coordinate (B) at (4,6);
  \coordinate (C) at (9,1);
  \draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
    \path[draw,color=red,line width=1.5,opacity=0.5] (A) circle (1.5);
    \tkzDrawBisector[opacity=0](B,A,C);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! The label should be inside the arc?

Comment: @Bobyandbob yes, these triangles are being mass generated so looking for a consistent way of doing this with arbitrary angle/sides etc.

Comment: You could use `\tkzLabelAngle[pos=1,circle](B,A,C){$60^{\circ}$}`.(Page 40 in the manual)

Comment: @Bobyandbob this appears to work perfectly, and thank you for the page reference.

Comment: If you disagree with the duplicate, let me know, we can always reopen. That question does seem to say just what @Bobyandbob said though.